# Lock thread while resource is empty

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locks

Very simplified version of My project. Multiple instances of `MyThread` try to get and remove one element form `Set` defined in `MyWorker` class and do some work with it.

In the rest of my code (not pasted here) I have at least one thread that is filling `Set` in `MyWorker` so there is no risk that `ParseNextPendingElement()` will never find element in Set.

My problem is that I don't know how to "lock" thread on empty set. Now I've implemented primitive delay after failed access to Set.
How can I achieve both waiting for Set to have at least one element and not stress CPU while waiting?

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private MyWorker worker;

    //constructors, get, set, etc.

    public void run() {
        worker.ParseNextPendingElement();
    }
}

private static class MyWorker {
    private Set set;

    //constructors, get, set, etc.

    public void ParseNextPendingElement() {
        Object elemToParse;

        while(1) {
            synchronized(set) {
                if(!set.isEmpty()) {
                    elemToParse = set.remove();
                    break;
                }
            }

            // BRUTAL workaround to not stress CPU while waiting for
            // at least one element in set.
            Thread.delay(100);
        }

        // Do some stuff with elemToParse
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to have a thread behavior that will enter into waiting state and will come back when you have a new input, that's sounds like a job for `LinkedBlockingQueue` from the `java.util.concurrent` package instead of just a Set.

`LinkedBlockingQueue` has a method `take()` that will enter a thread to waiting state if the queue is empty, and will come back when it'll have new items in it.